# validating the form is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

my form validation does not firing...if i try to submit this form without entering anything then it should validate but in this case it does accept the form.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#register").click(function (event) {
            // validate the comment form when it is submitted  
            // validate signup form on keyup and submit
            $("#form1").validate({
                rules: {
                    firstname: "required",
                    lastname: "required",
                    //city: "required",
                    state: "required",
                    country: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                    lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
                    //city: "Please enter a valid email address",
                    country: "Please select your country"
                }
            });
            $("#form1").validate({
                submitHandler: PostData
            });


            function PostData() {

                $.ajax(url, { Id: '1' },
                       function (data, textStatus) {
                           //alert(textStatus);
                       });
            }

        });
    });
</script>
<div id="content-main">
    <div class="main-inner">
        <form id="form1" class="toolTip hasCorners" name="form1" action="http://site.com/"
        onsubmit="return false;" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="fontWeight7">
                <input type="radio" value="1" name="pledge_level" class="required">
                <p class="radioText">
                    Iam on vacation.</p>
                <label for="level1" class="error">
                    Please select</label>
            </div>
            <p class="required-msg">
                All fields below are required</p>
            <div class="subColumns paragraph">
                <div class="lefty">
                    <div class="fontWeight7">
                        <label for="first_name">
                            First Name:</label>
                        <input id="first_name" class="text hasCorners required" name="first_name" type="text"
                            maxlength="200" value="">
                        <label for="level1" class="error">
                            Please enter your name!</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cdc-left">
                    <div class="fontWeight7">
                        <label for="last_initial">
                            Last Initial:</label>
                        <input id="last_initial" class="text hasCorners required" name="last_initial" type="text"
                            maxlength="200" value="">
                        <label for="level2" class="error">
                            Please enter your last initial!</label>
                    </div>
                   <rest of the code here .... >
                </div>
            </div>

<input id="register"   name="register" value="Submit Your form"
                                    type="submit">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.validate` should be done once the document is ready, not on the click of the button. So take it out from there.

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
                firstname: "required",
                lastname: "required",
                //city: "required",
                state: "required",
                country: "required"
            },
            messages: {
                firstname: "Please enter your firstname",
                lastname: "Please enter your lastname",
                //city: "Please enter a valid email address",
                country: "Please select your country"
            },
            submitHandler: PostData
        });
    });
});

function PostData() {
    $.ajax(url,
           { Id: '1' },
           function (data, textStatus) {
               //alert(textStatus);
           });
}
```

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: what would you put in the function (data, textStatus) {
               //alert(textStatus);
           });
????

Comment: I just copy and pasted the code from the question. To answer your question: I don't know! I don't even know if it's valid jQuery. Look here for more info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/